# Converting Image to HEX plain text same to what stored inside SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, byte

I have a Winforms application that uploads images to SQL Server 2005 as `Image` data type for SQL Server column within two methods `Single` and `Multiple`.

With single I send a parameter from C# to the SP as binary image.

But with multiple I need to send them as XML plain text to the DB and converting them inside the SP to image using

```
convert(image, @myimageFromXML, 2)
```

I tried many functions from other websites like

```
     public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
     {
         StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
         foreach (byte b in ba)
             hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
         return hex.ToString();
     }
     public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
     {
         string hex = BitConverter.ToString(ba);
         return hex.Replace("-", "");
     }

     public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] Bytes)
     {
         char[] hexes = new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F' };
         char[] Result = new char[Bytes.Length << 1];
         int Offset = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i != Bytes.Length; i++)
         {
             Result[Offset++] = hexes[Bytes[i] >> 4];
             Result[Offset++] = hexes[Bytes[i] & 0x0F];
         }
         return new string(Result);
     }
     public static String ByteArrayToString(byte[] Source)
     {
         return "0x" + BitConverter.ToString(Source).Replace("-", "");
     }

     public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] barray)
     {
         char[] c = new char[barray.Length * 2];
         byte b;
         for (int i = 0; i < barray.Length; ++i)
         {
             b = ((byte)(barray[i] >> 4));
             c[i * 2] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
             b = ((byte)(barray[i] & 0xF));
             c[i * 2 + 1] = (char)(b > 9 ? b + 0x37 : b + 0x30);
         }

         return new string(c);
     }
```

but every one of them returns data not correct and I cannot display them because it cannot be rendered as Image

My correct image within single document upload saved binary image starts with

```
 0x49492A008C040600803FA04FF004160D0784..........
```

but wrong data saved with multiple upload starts with

```
 0x310033003700380030003700380037.............
```

Please help me to find how to get correct binary data from C# byte[] in order to send them as XML to the SQL Server as a text

Comment: How are you rendering the data back?

Comment: [*ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to convert your image to Base64 string:

```
// Convert byte[] to Base64 String
string base64ImageString = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
```

some methods you need:

***Image to Base64 String***

```
public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

***Base64 String to Image***

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

codes from [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx).